# Spanning Table Cells automatically between same value cells

Tags: javascript

Please review my JavaScript code below. I want to colspan and rowspan automatically if adjacent cells have sames value. For example like this.

```
<table id="BeforeTable" border="1">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<table id="AfterTable" border="1">
    <tr><td>A</td><td colspan="2">B</td><td rowspan="2">C</td><td rowspan="2">D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have finished coding but I feel it is not sophisticated and I want to know more better way to solve the issue. Could you review my code below and give me any suggestions. (or if there is any solutions about this such as JavaScript libraries, please let me know.)

```
<table id="BeforeTable" border="1">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
</table>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    doColSpan();
    doRowSpan();
    deleteCellsByCol();
    deleteCellsByRow();
});
function doColSpan(){
    var colSpanCount = 1;
    var tObj=document.getElementById("BeforeTable");
    for(var i=0; i<tObj.rows.length; i++){
        if(tObj.rows[i]!=null){
            for(var j in tObj.rows[i].cells){
                if(tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML){
                    if(colSpanCount > 1){
                        colSpanCount--;
                        continue;
                    }
                    colSpanCount = getColSpanCount(tObj, i, j);
                    if(colSpanCount > 1){
                        tObj.rows[i].cells[j].colSpan = colSpanCount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function getColSpanCount(tObj, i, j){
    colSpanCount = 1;
    nextX = parseInt(j);
    while(true){
        nextX++;
        if(isEqualToNextRightCell(tObj, i, j, nextX)){
            colSpanCount++;
            continue;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return colSpanCount;
}
function isEqualToNextRightCell(tObj, i, j, nextX){
    return tObj.rows[i].cells[nextX] && tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == tObj.rows[i].cells[nextX].innerHTML
}
function doRowSpan(){
    var tObj=document.getElementById("BeforeTable");
    for(var i=0; i<tObj.rows.length; i++){
        if(tObj.rows[i]!=null){
            for(var j in tObj.rows[i].cells){
                if(tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML){
                    rowSpanCount = getRowSpanCount(tObj, i, j);
                    if(rowSpanCount > 1){
                        tObj.rows[i].cells[j].rowSpan = rowSpanCount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function getRowSpanCount(tObj, i, j){
    rowSpanCount = 1;
    nextY = parseInt(i);
    while(true){
        nextY++;
        if(isEqualToNextUnderCell(tObj, i, j, nextY)){
            rowSpanCount++;
            continue;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return rowSpanCount;
}
function isEqualToNextUnderCell(tObj, i, j, nextY){
    return tObj.rows[nextY] && tObj.rows[nextY].cells[j] && tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == tObj.rows[nextY].cells[j].innerHTML
}
function deleteCellsByCol(){
    var s="";
    var tObj=document.getElementById("BeforeTable");
    for(var i=0; i<tObj.rows.length; i++){
        if(tObj.rows[i]!=null){
            for(var j in tObj.rows[i].cells){
                if(tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML){
                    for(var k = 1; k < tObj.rows[i].cells[j].colSpan; k++){
                        tObj.rows[i].deleteCell(parseInt(j) + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function deleteCellsByRow(){
    var deletedCount = 0;
    var tObj=document.getElementById("BeforeTable");
    for(var i=0; i<tObj.rows.length; i++){
        if(tObj.rows[parseInt(i)+1]){
            for(var j in tObj.rows[i].cells){
                rowSpanCount = tObj.rows[i].cells[j].rowSpan;
                if(rowSpanCount > 1){
                    for(var k in tObj.rows[parseInt(i)+1].cells){
                        if(tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == tObj.rows[parseInt(i)+1].cells[k].innerHTML){
                            tObj.rows[parseInt(i)+1].deleteCell(k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't see a reason why these functions should be in the global scope. The easiest fix for that is to put everything inside your function called with `$(document).ready`.
2. `isEqualToNextRightCell`: Use the identity operation for comparison unless you're absolutely sure you want type conversion done automatically in the comparison. You also forgot the semicolon. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

   ```
   function isEqualToNextRightCell(tObj, i, j, nextX){
       return tObj.rows[i].cells[nextX] &&
           tObj.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML === tObj.rows[i].cells[nextX].innerHTML;
   }
   ```
3. `getColSpanCount`: Declare your variables, or they will be global. Also, you can tighten this up a bit by bringing your `if` into your `while`:

   ```
   function getColSpanCount(tObj, i, j) {
       var colSpanCount = 1,
           nextX = parseInt(j, 10);
       while (isEqualToNextRightCell(tObj, i, j, ++nextX)) {
           colSpanCount++;
       }
       return colSpanCount;
   }
   ```
4. `doColSpan`: You make a minor, but all-too-common JS mistake here by referencing Array.length directly in the for loop. When possible, store the length once and recycle it. You can also improve readability and performance by storing the array elements as you loop. Furthermore, you treat your arrays inconsistently. tObj.rows you loop over using old-style syntax. tObj.rows[i].cells you loop over using `for … in` syntax, which is cool, but isn't implemented everywhere yet. Here's how I would write it:

   ```
   function doColSpan() {
       var colSpanCount = 1,
           tObj = document.getElementById("BeforeTable"),
           i = tObj.rows.length,
           j,
           numCells,
           row,
           cell;
       while (i-- > 0) {
           row = tObj.rows[i];
           if (row) {
               j = 0;
               numCells = row.cells.length;
               while (j < numCells) {
                   cell = row.cells[j];
                   if (cell.innerHTML) {
                       if (colSpanCount > 1) {
                           colSpanCount--;
                           continue;
                       }
                       colSpanCount = getColSpanCount(tObj, i, j);
                       if (colSpanCount > 1) {
                           cell.colSpan = colSpanCount;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The rest of the code is much like the above, so I won't reiterate it. If you apply these principles throughout the code it should help. Don't forget to use a [code analyzer](http://www.jshint.com/) to help weed out the easy-to-fix stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much! you gave me a lot of information I'v never knew. such as..

Comment: >1 The easiest fix for ..  <br/>  I will do it right now. To be honest .. I did not know the differences between inside "$(document).ready" and its outside. Additionally,..

Comment: >2 Use the identity.. <br/> I'm reading the reference as you wrote. ..

Comment: I understood the meant of '===' finally. I will use it at another situations.